# Redux: Performance of list of connected components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, redux, react-redux

I have some `<List>` connected component which passes a lot of attributes to `<ListItem>` components. It is getting to the point where a refactor is needed because too many attributes are being passed down.

Suppose I turn the table and instead make `<ListItem>` a connected component so that I am not required to pass so many attributes down. Would I expect to see a performance degradation or improved performance of my UI rendering?

I've done some reading but wasn't able to find an exact answer to my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, connecting more components is better for performance, because the cost of running more `mapState` functions is less than the cost of doing more "wasted" component re-renders.

Please see the Redux FAQ entries on [performance](https://redux.js.org/faq/performance) and [connecting multiple components](https://redux.js.org/faq/reactredux#should-i-only-connect-my-top-component-or-can-i-connect-multiple-components-in-my-tree), and my blog post [Practical Redux, Part 6: Connected Lists and Performance](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/01/practical-redux-part-6-connected-lists-forms-and-performance/) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass all the props one by one. You may use the spread operator to pass all the props at once:

```
<List myProp={myProp} {...rest} />
```

This will send one prop `myProp` and all other props exists in the `rest` props.

Or, you can pass all the props:

```
<List {...props} />
```

In the `ListItem` component:

```
const { myOtherProp1, myOtherProp2 } = props
<ListItem myOtherProp1={myOtherProp1} myOtherProp2={myOtherProp2} />
```

---

Also, you may pass the default props which you think is required for the component:

```
List.defaultProps = {
  myOtherProp3: 'My default prop 3'
  myOtherProp10: 'My default prop 10'
}
```

This way you're passing all the props but use them when you need to use them.

---

To answer your exact question:

No. There'll be no performance hit. There's no limit of the props. You can pass as many as you want. The receiving component will get all the props from single source `props`.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @Bhojendra Rauniyar's answer to your exact question: Passing props doesn't slow down React because it doesn't copy the information, it just creates a pointer to it which is really cheap. Javascript works in general like this, for example:

```
a = {foo:'bar'}
b = a
b.foo = "another bar"
console.log(a.foo)
    > "another bar"
```

Javascript recycled the reference to `a.foo` rather than copying it to `b.foo`. So changing `b.foo` also changed `a.foo`.